# Two pods are different namespace different services , how to communicate each other?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to communicate with two pods with two different namespace and different service?

Comment: Downvoting as this question is generic Kubernetes and should not be tagged google-kubernetes-engine

Answer (score 1):

Two pods in different namespaces communicate via the domain name of the service. In your case if pod A (service A) wants to connect to pod B (service B) in namespace blue, it would need to connect to `b-service.blue` or the full name of

`b-service.blue.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have created a `service` to front the pods (`NodePort`, `ClusterIP` or `LoadBalancer`), you can access the pods using the format

`{name of service}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local`

So if the service you are trying to access resides in the namespace `redis` and is called `redis-standlone`, you would access it like this:

`redis-standalone.redis.svc.cluster.local`